# Is deformation of the impact attenuation system visible on the surviving Apollo command modules?

Tags: apollo-program, impact, command-module

As pointed out in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28065/26446), the Apollo command module had crushable ribs along one edge of the base of the cone, and crushable struts that suspended the crew couches inside the vehicle.  I've added some diagrams from [CSM06 Command Module Overview pp 39-52.pdf](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/CSM06_Command_Module_Overview_pp39-52.pdf) below.

By my count, 19 command modules returned to Earth: AS-201, AS-202, Apollo 4, Apollo 6-17, Skylab 2-4, and ASTP.  Most (all?) are in museums.  **Do any of these surviving command modules show visible deformation of the impact attenuation system** (either internal or external) **?**  Photographs would be helpful.

[image: Apollo external attenuation]

[image: Apollo internal attenuation]

Comment: May be deformation of the crushable ribs are not visible from the outside of the capsules, only from inside close to the ribs using a borescope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Photographs of Apollo 17 capsule:
(at the Space Center Houston museum)

[image: image1]
[image: image2]
[image: image3]
[image: image4]

Sorry if the lighting is making it hard to see; they keep it pretty dark in there. I didn’t see any visible deformation, anyway. I have more pictures, let me know if you want any area in particular.

Comment: Thanks for the pictures!  I would agree that they don't show any deformation.